# CSS: Arrange a list in multiple rows and columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an simple ordered list inside my template file, which I can't change.

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to order my content like so: two columns, the last item will always be on the second column.

[image]

I tried flex, but I couldn't find a way to break the flow after the third item. Is there a way to do this via CSS or will I have to resort to hacking it with jQuery?

Comment: BTW the sample code is invalid. Need to close the `li`s

Comment: @Aziz, although closing an `li` might be considered a best practice, it is not required in most cases. The OP's original HTML may have been incorrect but it was not invalid ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element)).

Comment: @Michael_B That's amazing, thanks for telling me. Of course, I did a small [test](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/h1jhsgoc/) ;)

Comment: @Aziz, and if you test [**your code**](https://jsfiddle.net/h1jhsgoc/2/) in the [**W3C HTML validator**](https://validator.w3.org/) (use Direct Input), it will pass. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Norbert Not much use but this can be achieved in Firefox https://jsfiddle.net/jqaksm74/1/. Unfortunately this won't work in any other browser and I believe there is still some discussion as to whether this is the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hacked away at this for hours and haven't managed to find a suitable solution that didn't involve a fixed height on the container. The closest thing I found was using the `column-count` property and adding a column break before the last element, which for now only works on Chrome:

```
ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}

li:last-of-type {
  -webkit-column-break-before: always;
}
```

#### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2es7p0qv/)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with **Flexbox** using `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap`, here is [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/218/)

**Update:** This is not great solution because you have to use fixed height on **parent** element also if your content overflows one of `li` it will break layout as you can see here [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/219/) **but** it could be useful in some cases.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  width: 50%;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #000000;
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #30BB75;
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #BB3047;
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background: #305EBB;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But is there a way to do it without making the container full height? In my situation, the content controls the height of the container.

Comment: At first this idea seemed great but now..., you can't use `min-height` also, maybe there is a way but i am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Nenad Vracar's answer, you can do the same with a dynamic number of elements, without having to resort to absolute percentages, using `flex-grow`. Example:

```css
ul {
  height: 200px; /* Whatever */
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  width: 50%;
  flex-grow: 1; /* Height will be distributed evenly */
}

li:last-of-type {
  flex: 0 0 100%; /* Last element will have 100% height,
                  thus occupying a new column */
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dv0071tn/)

Comment: Still, you need a fixed height. The only way I managed to do this is to set `column-count: 2` on the container and `-webkit-column-break-before: always` on the last element. Unfortunately this doesn't work on Firefox yet.

Comment: You do need a defined height on the `ul` (one that does not depend on the contents). But it doesn't have to be fixed in px; it can be a percentage of the parent, percentage of the viewport; or calculated by flex itself. See for example [this variation](https://jsfiddle.net/k3L03hbp/1/)